# How to remove files according to their MIME type?

Tags: files, find, delete

(Hello! And especially hello to everyone as it is my first post here.)

I want to remove files according to their MIME type with a command, in a folder and its sub-folders, say .webp and .png pictures. I have almost 0 computing knowledge but I already managed to remove them according to their extension.

First going on the wanted folder:

```
cd /my-folder
```

Then:

```
find \( -iname "*.webp" -o -iname "*.png" \) -print0 | xargs -0 rm -f
```

Someone already gave me an answer on another forum, the command works but it is VERY slow, like 10 seconds for 70 files, I can't use it because of this.

```
while read -d '' Fichier
do
  MimeType=$(mimetype --output-format %m "$Fichier") 
  [[ "${MimeType}" == @(image/webp|image/png) ]] && echo rm "$Fichier"
done < <(find . -type f -print0)
```

It seems yet a so "simple" task...

Comment: By the way, for "almost 0 computing knowledge", you're doing computing very well, congratulations!

Comment: @MarcusMüller Oh really? Well it's nice to you thank you! But well, after 10 years under Ubuntu I must have succeeded in learning a few tips, but not as much as I should have. I'm happy with the multi-remove line with `find`, but such a small line asked me several hours of readings and I don't even totally understand it, what a shame. :)

Answer (score 2):

`exiftool` could be used to report files identified of being a given MIME type:

```
exiftool -q -r. -ext '*' -if '
  print "$FilePath\0" if $MIMEType =~ m{^image/(webp|jpeg)$}; 0' . |
  xargs -r0 echo rm
```

(remove the `echo` if that looks right)

- `-q`: quiet
- `-r.`: recursive search (beware it follows symlinks to directories!) including in hidden directories
- `-ext '*'`: don't restrict to files with known extension
- `-if 'perl code'`: only reports info about files for which the code returns true. Here, we add a `;0` to return false so no file be selected because we want to print the file paths NUL-delimited which we do by calling `print` in the code instead. Doing `-if '$MIMEType eq "image/webp"' -s3 -FilePath` would print the paths newline-delimited which is not post-processable reliably since newline is as valid a character as any in a file path.

Or you could let `exiftool` delete the file itself:

```
exiftool -q -r. -ext '*' -if '
  if ($MIMEType =~ m{^image/(webp|jpeg)$}) {
    print STDERR "Deleting $FilePath\n";
    unlink $FilePath or print STDERR "Failed: $!\n";
  }
  0' .
```

Comment: Thank you the command works. Slightly slow (about 1min for 5000 files), but way faster than the one I had showed in my question (but `find` is lightning-fast). Yet there seems to be another problem, I have wanted to try it on other MIME types than the 2 image examples, and then often they don't work! Displaying nothing while there were files. Ones who succeeded: `application/zip`, `application/pdf`, `image/(webp|jpeg)`, `text/html`. Ones who gave nothing: `application/xhtml+xml`, `application/x-bzip-compressed-tar`, `application/x-ms-dos-executable`.

Comment: But then thanks to your comment, which was "`exiftool` will only report on the file types it knows (see man page for the list)", I could see the reason was effectively here (comment that is in your other answer, order is just a bit messed up because I made a few rearrangement of my comments). `zip` etc are in its list, so the command applies on them, and `xhtml+xml` etc are not, so the command doesn't. That makes the `exiftool` command not really usable for me too, as I will certainly want to remove mimetypes it doesn't recognize!

Answer (score 1):

`file` would likely be more efficient than your `mimetype`¹ or `exiftool` that are written in `perl` especially if you call it once for many files, which you could do with:

```
find . -type f -exec file -00 --mime-type {} + |
  perl -0lne '$file = $_; chomp($type = <>);
              print $file if $type =~ m{^image/(webp|jpeg)\z}' |
  xargs -r0 echo rm
```

Instead of `print $file`, you can do `unlink $file` and skip the `| xargs rm` part:

```
find . -type f -exec file -00 --mime-type {} + |
  perl -0lne '$file = $_; chomp($type = <>);
              if ($type =~ m{^image/(webp|jpeg)\z}) {
                warn "Deleting $file\n";
                unlink $file or warn "Failed: $!\n"
              }'
```

---

<sup>¹ `mimetype` in my tests also seems to struggle with file paths that are not UTF-8 encoded text, so probably can't cope with arbitrary file paths.</sup>

Comment: @UnixToo, sorry my bad. I had added the `chomp` to strip the delimiter (NUL) from the record returned by `<>`, but forgot  to change the `\0` in the pattern to `\z` (match at the end of the subject). Fixed now. `exiftool` will only report on the file types it knows (see man page for the list).

Comment: (Excuse me I deleted the first 2 comments because they were much about the "exiftool" answer, and I thought it made no sense to put them here, so I put them back in the "exiftool" answer, I hope it doesn't bother people.)

Comment: So then @Stéphane-Chazelas, you had answered with a comment and fixed your command after my comment that was (a bit edited): "Thanks, but the first command does nothing, I just copied/pasted it, was I supposed to do something else? Yet it interests me because it could be better than the `exiftool` one? Which seems to have (more) limitations.".

Comment: Command n°1/ In a tests4 folder with no subfolder and 2600 files (`.webp`, `.jpg`, `.html` and `.zip.html`), it worked and took 2:05 minutes (and with `find` by extensions, instantaneous, less than 1s). In a test on my /home folder, whith subfolders and 160 000 files, it took 32 minutes (and with `find` by extensions, 33s).

Comment: Command n°2/ On the tests4 folder, 2:13 (almost the same, and my timing is done manually so not very accurate), but it displayed, and also removed the files for real (maybe that brought the additionnal seconds), so I didn't try on my /home folder.

Comment: I guess the topic can be considered answered/closed now? (or almost). The command n°1 (my favorite) seems concerning speed an acceptable compromise between the `find` (fast but not as simply usable on mimetypes than on extensions) and the command given from another forum (very slow). I had imagined something as simple and almost as fast as `find \( -mimetype "image\/jpeg" \) -print0 -delete` but there doesn't seem to be such thing. So thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You could incorporate the test

```
find -type f \( -iname "*.webp" -o -iname "*.png" \) \
-exec bash -c 'grep image <<<"$(mimetype -b "$1")"' bash {} \; \
-delete
```

What it does:

1. line: search for files only (`type f`) and sieve out by names ending in `.webp` or `.png`
2. line: run a bash script where

   2.1. `mimetype b "$1"` returns the mimetype of argument no. 1 in the script only. `-b` skips returning the filename so the following string search does not coincidally include files where the name includes "image"

   2.2. Search for the string "image" in the returned mimetype using `grep`; `grep` succeeds (exit status `0`) if the string is found

   2.3. it all has to be wrapped in a bash script as command substitution will not work nicely with `find`;  note the argument numbering starts at `0` for `bash -c 'script' arg0 arg1 arg2 ...', hence the extra` bash`
3. line deletes any matches where the previous commands succeed. Maybe replace `-delete` with `-print` for a dry run showing what files are affected.

Also a hint regarding the `find | xargs rm`-combination in your question:

`find` has its own deletion tool:

```
find -name '*png' ....<other refinements> ... -delete
```

But be careful to only ever place `-delete` at the end. Way back, I leanrned that the hard way...

Comment: (Part 1).
Thank you, I tried the command, and it works, but not the way I would want, as it is as slow as the one I have showned in my question.
Maybe it is because of what you said, that I should put it in a script if I understand, but I don't know scripts yet, and for the moment I miss time to learn it...

Comment: (Part 2).
OK for `-delete`, so when instead of 
`find \( -iname "*.webp" -o -iname "*.jpg" \) -print0 | xargs -0 rm -f`
I put
`find \( -iname "*.webp" -o -iname "*.jpg" \) -print0 -delete`
it worked but it displayed what it had removed in the terminal.
I am wrong somewhere I guess (sorry for my low level).

Comment: (Part 3). I also must say that I didn't really understand the goal and the functioning of the command, despite your explanations that seem clear, sorry again for low level (and my english is a bit poor, and by now I miss a bit time to try thoroughly to understand).

Comment: @UnixToo no worries: It prints because you still have `-print0` in the command. Feel free to elaborate where exactly you are stuck in understanding. In the script part? Or with how `find` works? Explaining is way easier I one knows which part is missing for understanding.

Comment: (Thanks for proposal.) Like you had guessed, I didn't know the meaning of `-print0`! OK it prints/displays. So what surprised me is a bit clearer now, instead of "The second command displays the results", I can say "`-print0` is present in both commands, but only the second one displays the results".

Comment: (Part 1) About what I didn't understand, I think it has finally no real utility in fact, but yet I can try to explain myself! 1/ Please don't laugh, but the main thing that had given me a big doubt is the word "incorporate". I had thought it would mean "in your test, incorporate this test", i.e. "add this test into your tests", so I was a bit lost. But now I guess it simply means "incorporate this test among the other tests". (That is for "the goal".) 2/ For 1. line I understand the command (and (logically) the "What it does"), which is "normal" as I spent hours of reading to find it.

Comment: (Part 2) But for the 2.1. line, I don't understand the command, which is "normal" too given my "low level" like I said, but neither the "What it does", which is a bit more problematic. (That is an example for "the functioning".) BUT I shouldn't have said that as I think it is already implied/understood given my "low level", so I'm supposed not to understand, so not to say it if it is the case. More precisely, I would say I read several times the commands (and the "What it does), I see 1 or 2 small bits, and more or less the overall idea, well it's better if I do, but if I don't, "never mind".

Comment: (Part 3) I would try harder to understand and maybe ask explanations if I see that this command approaches the goal I search for and even can possibly be improved, but otherwise, if I ask an explanation "just" because I don't understand, I'm afraid the page will become a long low level command line tutorial! (Sorry a bit long for not nothing much.)

Comment: I think I had mistaken "2.3. it all has to be wrapped in a bash script as command substitution will not work nicely with `find`". To me it meant "put the whole command in a script, because simply pasting it in the Terminal won't work very well", that's why I said "but I don't know scripts yet". But I think that it is just that a part of the command is under the form of a script!

Comment: A remark: I think that in 1. line, writing the extensions doesn't fit to what I search for, because I really want to skip the extension criterion, as the mimetype criterion must apply also on files with no extension, or with wrong extension (that might happen I guess), and if I understand, by doing this those 2 cases won't be taken into account.

Comment: As you may have seen, by now, if I don't err, what works best for me (= the fastest, and not ignoring mimetypes like `exiftool`) is the n°1 command of @Stéphane-Chazelas answer (not the `exiftool` answer). Before leaving, I tested again with the command of this answer, and it was faster: "tests4" folder (no subfolder, 2600 files): 20s instead of 2:05 min., /home folder (subfolders and 160 000 files): 3:40 min. instead of 32 min. BUT I guess it is sped up because of the sieving out by extension (?), and like I said just before in "A remark" it is a thing I do want to avoid, too bad.

Comment: Still interested in any better command (or the improvement of a one already here). :) Thanks for answer, and the proposal of further explanations!